# Data structure for Redis (no-sql) application

Tags: data-structures, nosql, redis

I am new to No-SQL and am trying to figure out a good way to structure a poll application.  Basically, there will be a poll question, around 5 possible choices, and user ids.

What is the best way to make the data structure for this?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Before scoping your question to No-SQL or to Redis in particular, you have to figure out your requirements. i.e. what will be the load, what's the persistent database you want to go with (before you get to memory based solutions like Redis) etc.

Comment: True. In the land of nosql, one of the main topics is: How will you query the data? Many systems do not allow you to "add an index" later, rather the non-schema needs to be designed properly from the start...  maybe just use ms sql/postgress?